# How to summarize records into multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry if the title does not make sense but I cant seem to find the word for what exactly I am trying to do

I know how to create pivots using group by function and sum, max values in SQL server. However, my question is this

I have data like so:

```
Filename     Branch   Name         
1              1      Joe Test     
2              2      Joseph Test  
3              3      Smith Test
```

Each filename has multiple borrowers associated, I need to join borrowerid to the table on filename when I do so this happens:

```
Filename     Branch     Name        Borrowerid
1              1         Joe Test    123
1              1         Joe Test    345
1              1         Joe Test    678
2              2         Joseph Test 412
2              2         Joseph Test 214
3              3         Smith Test  333
```

How can place each borrower in its own column such as borrower1, borrower2, borrower?

For example

```
Filename    Branch     Name      BorrowerId   BorrowerId2   BorrowerId3 
1            1        Joe Test     123          345            678
2            2        Joseph Test  412          214
3            3        Smith Test   333
```

Please assist in helping how to do this

Thank you

Comment: use PIVOT to get to it

Comment: what is the maximum number of borrowers a filename can have?

Comment: Maximum number of borrowers is 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIVOT and/or DYNAMIC PIVOT is what you are looking for, however, I use a stored procedure for the bulk of my dynamic pivots

```
Exec [prc-Pivot] 'Select *,NewCol=concat(''Borrowerid'',Row_Number() over (Partition By FileName,Branch,Name Order By Borrowerid)) from YourTable','NewCol','max(Borrowerid)[]','FileName,Branch,Name','count(*)[Records]'
```

Returns

```
FileName    Branch  Name         Records    Borrowerid1 Borrowerid2   Borrowerid3
1           1       Joe Test      3         123         345           678
2           2       Joseph Test   2         214         412           NULL
3           3       Smith Test    1         333         NULL          NULL
```

The stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc-Pivot] (
    @Source varchar(1000),          -- Any Table or Select Statement
    @PvotCol varchar(250),          -- Field name or expression ie. Month(Date)
    @Summaries varchar(250),        -- aggfunction(aggValue)[optionalTitle]
    @GroupBy varchar(250),          -- Optional additional Group By 
    @OtherCols varchar(500) )       -- Optional Group By or aggregates
AS

--Exec [prc-Pivot] 'Select Year=Year(TR_Date),* From [Chinrus-Series].[dbo].[DS_Treasury_Rates]','''Q''+DateName(QQ,TR_Date)','avg(TR_Y10)[-Avg]','Year','count(*)[Records],min(TR_Y10)[Min],max(TR_Y10)[Max],Avg(TR_Y10)[Avg]'
--Exec [prc-Pivot] '#Temp','Attribute','max(Description)[]','ID','count(*)[Records]'

Set NoCount On

Declare @Vals varchar(max),@SQL varchar(max);
Set @Vals = ''
Set @OtherCols= IsNull(', ' + @OtherCols,'')
Set @Source = case when @Source Like 'Select%' then @Source else 'Select * From '+@Source end
Create Table #TempPvot  (Pvot varchar(100))
Insert Into #TempPvot
Exec ('Select Distinct Convert(varchar(100),' + @PvotCol + ') as Pvot FROM (' + @Source + ') A')
Select @Vals = @Vals + ', isnull(' + Replace(Replace(@Summaries,'(','(CASE WHEN ' + @PvotCol + '=''' + Pvot +  ''' THEN '),')[', ' END),NULL) As [' + Pvot ) From #TempPvot Order by Pvot
Drop Table #TempPvot
Set @SQL = Replace('Select ' + Isnull(@GroupBy,'') + @OtherCols + @Vals + ' From (' + @Source + ') PvtFinal ' + case when Isnull(@GroupBy,'')<>'' then 'Group By ' + @GroupBy + ' Order by ' + @GroupBy else '' end,'Select , ','Select ')
--Print @SQL
Exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems like it should. If only I could figure out how to execute it. You have some parameters created as optional but it is still asking for those parameters to be passed. By chance can you show me an example on how you would call this proc?

Comment: NVM your a genius, You wrote it right in front of me. Thank you so much! This is amazing

Comment: @HuzaifaMAamir I keep telling my wife that I'm a genius.   She's knows better

Comment: If I wanted to limit the borrowers columns to only display borrower 1 and 2 how would I go about doing so? I've been trying to edit your code but I am not having any lucks -- Thanks